# Memory Leaks by Subclassing SKScene

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I'm using `Xcode8` and `Swift 3`.
After creating a new `SpriteKit` project, the top of GameScene.swift defines `GameScene` as child class of `SKScene`.

When the project is running in the Simulator, I press the Symbol for the Debug Memory Graph (three small connected circles above the Debug Area). As expected, there are no memory issues.

Now, I add a new class (called ParentScene) to GameScene.swift:

[GameScene has a new parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EYaQ.png)

Now, `SKScene` is the parent of ParentScene, and ParentScene is the new parent of GameScene.
Running this project in the Simulator and capturing the memory graph leads to the following issues:

[memory issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSi5e.png)

When running the project on my iPhone instead, the memory graph does not report any leaking objects.
My actual `SpriteKit` game project is also implementing a ParentScene between `SKScene` and `GameScene` and is triggering the memory issues in the Simulator AND on my device.

What is the reason for the leaking objects?

Comment: I do not think the issue is creating the parent class,  You can test this out easily by making a new project, and doing what you are asking before you add your content.  You will have to analyze your code better and come back to us when you have found what is causing the problem

Comment: Hello @Knight0fDragon, maybe there is a misunderstanding. You wrote: "You can test this out easily by making a new project, ..." But this is exactly the thing I was doing: I was debugging my game project for a long time, removing more and more of my code to encircle the cause for the memory leaks, but without success. So, I decided to approach the problem from the opposed side and created a clean, new `SpriteKit` project. I was totally surprised by triggering these memory leaks only by adding an empty class between `GameScene` and `SKScene`. You say: "analyze your code better" ... Which code?

Comment: You are definitely not doing that,  create a brand new project, and only add a parent class.  You will see it doesn't leak, it can't leak because all of those things are not even added that you claim are leaking.  If you are getting a leak, then delete Xcode because something messed up on your machine.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I do not say these leaks really exist, I just describe the output of the Debugger. Now, I switched to my older Mac, upgraded to Sierra, completely removed `Xcode7`, installed `Xcode8`, created a new, untouched `SpriteKit` project, let it run in the iPhone7 Simulator, captured the Memory Graph: no leaks. After pushing the empty class between `GameScene` and `SKScene`: long list of leaks. After removing the empty class: again, no list of leaks. By the way, the debugger output for the "leaking" project is non deterministic, it changes from run to run.

Comment: I would recommend you taking your project and moving it to another machine then, maybe put windows on yours because you got something broken

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, I think you misread my last comment. I already moved to another/second machine ("switched to my older Mac"). It is unlikely that both Macs are broken in the same way. I wonder if this could be a bug within the Visual Memory Debugger. After all, the Debug Memory Graph is a very new feature...