# Wrong configuration of Xcode's Visual Memory Debugger or is it a bug?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm using `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3` for developing `SpriteKit` games. This is my second stackoverflow question and it's an extension of my first ([Memory Leaks by Subclassing SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041163/memory-leaks-by-subclassing-skscene)). It is still unanswered but the focus of my question changed, so I decided to ask a new question instead of editing the old one.

Short version of my question:
After adding a few lines of really simple `Swift` code to a clean, new project, the Debug Memory Graph shows a mysterious list of allegedly leaking objects.
Is it possible that I just have to change the configuration of the Visual Memory Debugger?

Long version:
At some point of my app development, I noticed that the Debug Memory Graph shows a list of leaking objects. After some time of debugging, I realized that I can reproduce a similar debugger-output just by adding an extreme short and simple code snippet to a new `SpriteKit` project:

```
//  GameScene.swift
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

        /*** Begin of Code Snippet ***/
        enum MyEnum {
            case a
            case b
        }
        private var myVar : MyEnum?
        /*** End of Code Snippet ***/

        private var label : SKLabelNode?
        private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?
        ...
```

That's all! The list of leaking objects looks like this:

[image: List of Leaking Objects]

I always get a list like this when running the project in the simulator. When running the project on my iPhone, I have to push the App in the background at least once to trigger the leaks.

I don't think that I have a problem with my `Xcode` installation because I can reproduce the problem on two different machines. It also doesn't help to clean the project, reset the simulator and/or delete the complete content of the DerivedData folder.

I also tried to learn more about the Visual Memory Debugger (for example by watching the video "Visual Debugging with Xcode" from the WWDC 2016) but I couldn't find any hint for solving my problem.

By the way: My first question ([Memory Leaks by Subclassing SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041163/memory-leaks-by-subclassing-skscene)) addresses another code snippet that triggers the problem.

I am totally helpless here. Is anybody out there who has a similar problem with the new Visual Memory Debugger? Could it be a bug within the debugger?

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug either in the leak detection or in Sprite Kit. If you could file a report at bugreport.apple.com along with a sample project, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I will do that!